# Why CMake generate Makefile without CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, flags

This is my full CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow")

set(PROJECT sample)
project(${PROJECT})

set(HEADERS
    Main.h
)
set(SOURCES 
    Main.cpp
)

# Add souce file to project for compile
add_executable (${PROJECT} ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT} )
```

But, in Makefile i don't seek substring "-Wall" and other option from CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is initially set with the `project()` command. Move the `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ...")` after the `project()` command.

From [CMake Toolchains -
 Languages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#languages) documenation:

> Languages are enabled by the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#command:project) command. Language-specific built-in variables, such as [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html#variable:CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER), [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html#variable:CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_ID) etc are set by invoking the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#command:project) command. If no project command is in the top-level CMakeLists file, one will be implicitly generated. By default the enabled languages are `C` and `CXX`.

**References**

- [CMake and Make need to be run twice in order to build code successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684410/cmake-and-make-need-to-be-run-twice-in-order-to-build-code-successfully)
- [CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)

Comment: Thanks, this is work. But where in official documentation told about this feature (after the project)? I found project page https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/project.html but there is nothing said about the CXX option and project.

Comment: @Xintrea It's part of the [CMake Toolchains -
 Languages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#languages) documentation. I'll add this to my answer.