# Passing in CMake Flags through CMake CLI

Tags: c++, c, cmake

**Background**

CMake has the option to pass in an environment variable CFLAGS to prepend to the CMAKE_C_FLAGS environment variable used in compiling. I am using this option running CMake in a windows platform.

Ex (enabling the `-Wall` compiler flag):

```
cmake -E env CFLAGS="-Wall" cmake <path-to-source>
```

The above command is supposed to create a temporary environment and set *CFLAGS* to `-Wall` and then run `cmake` again within this temporary environment. [It is a proposed solution in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284275/passing-compiler-options-cmake). **HOWEVER**, it does not work as expected. The `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` are not initialized with the `CFLAGS` passed through. When printing the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` at the beginning of the *CMakeLists.txt* the set value for `-Wall` does not appear.

This is a distinct functionality from simply setting the *CMAKE_C_FLAGS* environment value using the `-D` option specified in the [CMake CLI Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html).

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Wall" <path-to-source>
```

Doing so will override the system variables set by CMake which leads to compilation failure. For instance in our project the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` can be seen to be by default set to:

```
CMAKE FLAGS: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
```

However if the `cmake -D` code is run, it will overwrite the initial `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`:

```
CMAKE FLAGS: -Wall
```

In the cmake documentation it explains:

> **CFLAGS - CMake 3.11.4 Documentation**
>
> Default compilation flags to be used when compiling C files. Will only
>   be used by CMake on the first configuration to determine CC default
>   compilation flags, after which the value for CFLAGS is stored in the
>   cache as CMAKE_C_FLAGS. For any configuration run (including the
>   first), the environment variable will be ignored if the CMAKE_C_FLAGS
>   variable is defined.

Now there is a workaround for this if one has the ability to adjust the CMakeLists.txt file itself, which is to create a `-D` option parameter that accepts an arbitrary string and appends it to the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.

```
if (NOT "${compileOption_C}" STREQUAL "OFF")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${compileOption_C} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

However this is a bit of a bodge and does not answer why the initial `CFLAGS` option does not work.

**Question**

**How does one add compiler flags using the CMake CLI without overwriting cached or default `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` values, knowing that `CFLAGS` is not working as intended?**

Comment: It's not possible (at least I don't see how it could be possible based on how CMake works) to append compiler flags using the CMake CLI.  You'll have to update the CMakelists.txt files to append compiler flags.

Comment: @Fred that seems to oppose what the documentation states and what [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284275/passing-compiler-options-cmake) proposes.

Comment: Those answers don't append compiler flags.  They either make a new build type and change the defaults for that build type or set the CFLAGS to influence the initial values of the default build types.  Either way if the CMakelist.txt file contains any target_compile_options commands those will be appended (or prepended) to the flags used.   All you can do is add options to the defaults or override the defaults both of which are described in the Background section of the OP.

Comment: In the case of setting the CFLAGS to influence the initial values of the default build types, wouldn't that be equivalent to prepending compiler flags in the CLI?

Comment: I guess you could call adding a value to an empty list prepending or appending or whatever.  Anyways a CMakeLists.txt can simply set CMAKE_C_FLAGS to anything it wants ignoring anything you did at the command line (for example libvncserver 0.9.11 does this).  Which is why I don't think there is an answer to your question.  As to why setting CFLAGS didn't work in this case is harder to tell because it does work (in general).  The question should probably be updated to clarify that appending isn't strictly needed and that adding -Wall didn't work.

Comment: Will update accordingly.

Comment: Not a duplicate. That answer does not answer my question. As stated in the background, the proposed solution in the answer, which I linked in my above comment already, does not work.