# How to compile C++ as CUDA using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I'm writing some code that can be compiled as C++ or as CUDA.  In the latter case, it makes use of CUDA kernels, in the former it just runs conventional code.

Having created a file named test.cpp, I can compile it manually thus:

```sh
g++ test.cpp          # build as C++ with GCC
nvcc -x cu test.cpp   # build as CUDA with NVCC
```

where `-x cu` tells nvcc that although it's a .cpp extension, I'd like it to treat it as CUDA. 
So far, so good.

However, when I migrate to using CMake, I don't know how to do the same thing.  That is: how to ask CMake to compile the .cpp file with NVCC, rather than GCC.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(cuda_test LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)
add_executable(cuda_test test.cpp)     # builds with GCC
```

If I create a symlink to the original file:

```sh
ln -s test.cpp test.cu
```

then change CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(cuda_test test.cu)     # builds with NVCC
```

But I'd like to be able to specify the equivalent of NVCC's `-x` switch within CMake, rather than playing games with extensions.  Something *like*:

```
set_target_properties(cuda_test PROPERTIES FORCE_LANGUAGE CUDA)
```

or even

```
set_target_properties(test.cpp PROPERTIES FORCE_LANGUAGE CUDA)
```

Does such an incantation exist?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284275/passing-compiler-options-cmake

Comment: For tell CMake to use CUDA compiler for a **source file**, you may set [LANGUAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html) property for that file: `set_source_file_properties(test.cpp PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)`.

Comment: Thanks @sweenish, but I don't think that's the same question.  I can pass compiler-specific arguments okay but  not specify the compiler in the first place.  That is, if I do `target_compile_options(cuda_test PRIVATE "-x cu")` the flag gets passed to GCC, not NVCC.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, it's `...files...` but otherwise that's exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much.  Please make it an answer rather than a comment and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, CMake chooses compiler for a source file according to the file's extension. But you may force CMake to use the compiler you want by setting [LANGUAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html) property for a file:

```
set_source_files_properties(test.cpp PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)
```

(This just calls CUDA compiler for a file using normal compiler options. You still need to pass additional options for that compiler, so it could work with the unusual file's extension.)

Comment: I realise I'm just being a pain now, but...  I'm now limited to _only_ compiling this file as CUDA, since the property is file- rather than target-specific.  I'm going to look around for an answer, but wondered if you had a magic solution to this too?!

Comment: @EddInglis Note, you can list *all* the source files in the same call: `set_source_files_properties(test.cpp test2.cpp test3.cpp PROPERTIES ...)` or you can provide a variable containing a list of all the sources instead.

Comment: Thanks, @squareskittles, that's handy.  What I meant, though, was once I've set the property on test.cpp, now CMake will always compile it with NVCC.  Ideally I could build it with either GCC or NVCC.  Rather than complicating this question, I'll ask a new one.  Cheers.

Comment: In CMake single **target** may contain source files for **different languages**. So, compile language is not a property for a target. (There is target property [LINKER_LANGUAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_tgt/LINKER_LANGUAGE.html) for specify language for the linker, but linking and compiling are separate steps.)