# CMake file properties per-target

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I previously asked: [How to compile C++ as CUDA using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58861467/11603085) which was super helpful.  But then realised I had a follow-on question.

What I want to do is compile one file twice, using different compilers.  eg:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(cuda_test LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

add_executable(cuda_test_host test.cpp)     # build with GCC for host

set_source_files_properties(test.cpp PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)
add_executable(cuda_test_cuda test.cpp)     # build with NVCC for CUDA
```

But of course, the `set_source_files_properties` is not specific to a particular target, so both `cuda_test_host` and `cuda_test_cuda` end up being built by NVCC.

I've seen similar questions on StackOverflow suggesting making sub-directories with different CMake files in, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: You could use a symbolic link to give the same file another name. Add one to first target and another to the second.

Comment: With [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) you can modify some [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets) on a target level. Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: @eerorika, I had that idea in my first post.  It's certainly very appealing as a one-off, but less practical in my wider setup.  Thanks for your input though.

Comment: This is not supported in CMake. Language is a per-file property, not a binary per-file-and-target property (and certainly not a per-user-defined-target property).