# How to tell CMake to compile all cpp files as CUDA sources

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I have a project that has many .cpp files.
Mainly for testing, I like to compile these .cpp files as CUDA files.

I can overwrite the language automatically detected by CMake with this like for *each* file.

```
... loop of ${TEST_FILE} (from a list list of cpp files)
        set(TEST_EXE "${TEST_FILE}.x")
        add_executable(${TEST_EXE} ${TEST_FILE})

        if(FORCE_CUDA)
            set_source_files_properties(${TEST_FILE} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)
        endif()
...
```

**Is there a global setting by which I can tell CMake to compile `.cpp` files as if they were `.cu` (CUDA) sources?**

There is this related question, [How to compile C++ as CUDA using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861467/how-to-compile-c-as-cuda-using-cmake), but it only answers for individual or explicit lists of files (one has to `set_source_file_properties` in all locations of a long and subdirectory nested CMake files).

Comment: Couldn’t you set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to nvcc and then CXXFLAGS to include the -x cu switch?

Comment: Note, that if you want to create a separate executable for every source file, then you need `foreach` loop even if the global CUDA setting exists.

Comment: @talonmies, that's clever, but it sounds like a rabbit hole of pain; all the CUDA options (architectures, standards, warnings) would need to be passed, too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, true. Perhaps there is a "postscript" option that can convert all executables accumulated to the end of CMake to see their properties to CUDA LANGUAGE. However, a fundamental problem is that LANGUAGE is a property of the source, not the target executable.

Comment: @alfC: I don’t understand. If you have C++ code, by definition it doesn’t contain any CUDA code which requires any architecture settings, etc. So it cannot cause the compiler to hand anything to the device code compiler which would require any of those options

Comment: @talonmies, that is a good point. However, setting other options consistently could be difficult (optimization, warnings, etc). The main idea is to prove that a library compiles (through all the tests), not only with a c++ compiler but also with a specific CUDA compiler (such as nvcc, cuda clang, nvhpc, etc)

Comment: @talonmies: I think your idea won't work, because there are CUDA-specific CMake mechanisms which don't exist for C++,  like the handling of separable device compilation, and architectures etc. - and you couldn't make it work by "passing the options" as alfC suggests.

Comment: @einpoklum there is no CUDA code here. It’s plain C++ which the OP wants to pass through the CUDA toolchain for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scouring the CMake documentation for something relevant, I conclude  that this is not currently possible, and you will have to set the language file-by-file.